# Analytics on Xamarin + Parse

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform

I'm using parse to do some analytics, push et al on a Xamarin app. Given that not everything is available on the Windows SDK, is it possible to do something like

```
[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo]
```

Using the standard REST API? Can't find the related docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Parse:

> Right now there's no way to track an app open from a push notification
>   from the REST API; the reason being we do some transformations to the
>   data the application sends to the phone which are not publicly
>   available.

My solution: generate a unique ID per push, assign it to the JSON payload and track a custom event using the unique ID.